# If $\vec A= (2,1,-2),\vec A+\vec B= \vec A \times \vec B$. Then $\vec B=$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Tried to square both sides, led me nowhere though.

Comment: What do you mean by “square both sides?”

Comment: Think about it geometrically: $A\times B$ is orthogonal to both $A$ and $B$, while $A$, $B$ and $A+B$ are coplanar. How can both be possible?

Comment: @amd, I meant squaring Using dot product on LHS. The only solution I can think of is the origin point's vector.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring seems to work:
$$
\begin{align}
|A+B|^2
&=(A+B)\cdot(A\times B)\\
&=A\cdot(A\times B)+B\cdot(A\times B)\\
&=0+0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I tried this the long way:

$(2,1,-2)+(x,y,z)=(2+x,1+y,-2+z)$

$(2,1,-2)\times(x,y,z)=(z+2y,-2x-2z,2y-x)$

and solved $2+x=z+2y, 1+y=-2x-2z, -2+z=2y-x$

using a usual technique for a system of linear equations

to get $(x,y,z)=(-2,-1,2)$.

Then I saw $(2,1,-2)+(-2,-1,2)=\vec 0$, and realized the hint from [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd)

that $A+B$ is coplanar with $A$ and $B,$ and $A\times B$ is perpendicular to $A$ and $B$,

so $A+B=A\times B$ is possible only if $A+B=A\times B=\vec 0$.